# Add values in a CRUD table using angular

Tags: angular

I was making a CRUD table today and I seem to get a lot of errors therefore I cant mention all of them in the title of the question. Please excuse me for this mistake.This is a simple table not the angular material table yet I am finding it immensely difficult to debug it and get the desired output.These are my files

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="container">
<br>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" #uname placeholder="user name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" #uage placeholder="age">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" #ugender placeholder="gender">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" #uaddress placeholder="address">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onCreateUser(uname,uage,ugender,uaddress)">add user</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <table class="table">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor = "let tcol of thedrs">
            {{tcol}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let trow of trows">
          <td *ngFor = "let tcol of thedrs">
            {{trow[tcol]}}
           </td>
         </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
          <td>
          {{user.name}}
          </td>
          <td>
          {{user.age}}
          </td>
          <td>
          {{user.gender}}
          </td>
          <td>
          {{user.address}}
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngForTable';
  users = [];
  
  thedrs = [ 'Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Address'];
  trows = [{
    name: 'abc',
    age: 26,
    gender: 'female',
    address: 'usa'
  },
  {
    name: 'def',
    age: 27,
    gender: 'male',
    address: 'denmark'
  },
  {
    name: 'ghi',
    age: 25,
    gender: 'others',
    address: 'finland'
  }
  ];
  onCreateUser(uname,uage,ugender,uaddress){
    this.users.push({
      name: uname.value
      age: uage.value
      gender: ugender.value
      address: uaddress.value
    });
  }
}
```

Please debug the code so that I can get the desired ***output*** of a table in which I can add values through the input box which can be later viewed in table .Here the table already contains some values which are mentioned in the code.Also I am getting the following error message 3 times i.e. on age,gender and address in **app.component.ts**
**error 1**

```
',' expected. ts[1005]
```

**error 2**
In createUser() in app.component.ts I am getting dotted line under uname,uage,ugender,uaddress.The *fixes* that are shown are:

```
1)Infer parameter types from usage 
2)Infer all types from usage
3)convert parametrs to destructured object
```

**error 3**  
This is the photo of how my output looks right now.Please debug my code to display table and values that can be added.

[output in localhost:4200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqPIv.png)

Comment: Being candid, "Please debug the code" isn't received well. Learning to debug is a way to understand how angular works and how your code works. What may help is starting with a simpler example (a table with one row maybe) and build it up from there.

Comment: @stealththeninja Thanks for replying :) .I have made some edits . Please suggest relevant answer.

Comment: As per your advice I started with one row but now that row is now not seen instead table is able to add data.Please help how to display row from above code . Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add comma for separating properties when adding user object as

```
 this.users.push({
      name: uname.value,
      age: uage.value,
      gender: ugender.value,
      address: uaddress.value
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Hien Nguyen :) .Thanks a million for the help. But unfortunately I have some more errors.Can you Please debug it?Thanks :)

Comment: what is your more errors? can you put your full code in question?

Comment: I have shared the errors in the question by editing it. its error 3 .Please have a look. :) .Thanks